# Define and Access $rootScope with controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble on using `controller as` when i need to define a $rootScope variable value.

The process consists of 2 main phases.

- User is not logged, so when he process the login form I'll defini his personal data (like name and id) on the $rootScope inside the `LoginController`.
- User is already logged in (with data in the localStorage) so I'll get his data from the localStorage and set the `$rootScope` value on the `.run`;

But the problem is, since I'm new to this type of syntax (using 'controller as' with vm attr) the `$rootScope` is not being defined nor being access by the view.

This is what I'm doing:

#### .run

```
angular
    .module('agApp')
    .run(runAuth);

    /* @ngInject */
    function runAuth($rootScope,factAuth,localStorageService) {

        var user = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get("user"));
        if (user.length > 0) {
            $rootScope.userData = user[0];
        }

        $rootScope.logOut = function() {
            factAuth.logOut();
            $rootScope.userData = '';
            $state.go('login');
        };

    }; //end run
```

#### Controller

```
angular
    .module('agApp')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    /* @ngInject */
    function LoginController($rootScope,$http,$state,localStorageService,factAutenticacao) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.pageName = 'Login page';

        vm.loginProccess = loginProccess;

        function loginProccess(event) {
            //here i get an $htt to validate the login
            if (!data) {
                alert('login failed')
            } else {
                factAutenticacao.loginProcess();
                localStorageService.set("user", JSON.stringify(data[0]));
                $rootScope.userData = data[0];
                $state.go('app');
            };
        };

    }; //end login controller
```

By the way, the same problem happens when defining a global function, like the 'logOut' function.

And inside my view, I'm trying to access this data like this:

```
<div class="col-l-12">
    <h3>User: {{::vm.userData.name}}</h3>
    <ul>
        <li> {{::vm.userData.id}}</li>
        <li> {{::vm.userData.location}}</li>
        [.. more code ..]
    </ul>
</div>
```

Since it's a global var, i don't want to associate it with a particular `controller` because it needs to be accessible in the whole app.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you thought about abstracting the userData and logout function to a separate service that uses the localStorageService?

Comment: I'm doing this right now. But for example, i need to display the user data, and also use it's data, such as uniqueID in other ocasions, for example: adding a new product, open a ticket, etc.. Would it be possible? I'm trying to build the login/authentication as a separate module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view uses `vm.userData`, where `vm` is the controller itself. So, if you want that to work, userData must be a field of the controller, not a field of the root scope:

```
vm.userData = data[0];
```

instead of

```
$rootScope.userData = data[0];
```

Or, if you really want to store that on the $rootScope, then the view should use

```
{{ userData.name }}
```

to get the userData from the controller scope, and, by inheritance, from the root scope.

I agree with the comments though: that shouldn't be in the root scope. It should be inside a dedicated service, injected in whatever controller needs access to the user data.

Comment: I kind of built my workflow now. But let's say, this userData is used to display a Welcome message on the left navbar with the business logo, and also in the main view to define the user's ticket. You mean i'd better have a factory service to call this data when it's needed instead of a rootScope definition? Because this is the only rootScope I'm planning to use. I know it's something i should avoid.

Comment: I'd much prefer to have it exposed by a service, yes.

Comment: Ok. I'll follow this workFlow. But what about the logout process? How should i call this? Can you provide a basic example on this?